# Automatically select parent page if custom field equals page title

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, parent, advanced-custom-fields, page-title

Is it possible to automatically set/select a parent page on page creation when a custom field and page title are equal?

Example:

I have the following page hierarchy:

- Providers

  - Provider Page (Page title = user1)

    - Provider Package

When a new page is created, and the custom field value is “user1” and there is a page with the title “user1”. Then the Provider Page, in this case “user1”, should automatically be set as the parent for the page that is created (Provider Package page).

I hope it is a bit clear because it is quite difficult to explain I notice myself.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: parent page? or are you talking about assigning a post category/taxonomy if the required condition is achieved?

Comment: No. when a user creates a new page where the Custom field value is equal to a page title the parent page of the page that the user is creating should be the page that matched with his titile to the custom field value.... I know it sounds complex... Do you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using post editing hook filters/actions. Like this

```
 add_action( 'edit_post', 'parentsetter_save_post' );
    function parentsetter_save_post()
    {
      global $post;
      $custom_field=get_post_meta($post->ID,'customfieldname',true);

      if ($custom_field!=''){
        $parent_page=get_page_by_title($custom_field);
        if (!empty($parent_page) and $post->post_parent!=$parent_page->ID){
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("update $wpdb->posts set post_parent=%d 
            where ID=%d",$parent_page->ID,$post->ID));
          }
      }
    }
```

Just replace "customfieldname" with your custom field name and it will work.

Comment: Hello Elvin, thank you very much for the reply. I tried your code but it aint working. I changed the 'customfieldname' for the my own custom field but nothing happened. Custom Field = Provider1 and I have a page with the page title Provider1 but when I create a new page the parent page "Provider1" is not selected.

Comment: You need to clarify one thing: What is "Provider1"? Is it value of  custom field or it is the name of custom field? My code is for the case where Provider1 is the value of custom field called "customfieldname"

Comment: Hello Elvin, I tried your code again, change 'edit_post' to 'wp_insert_post' and now it is working. Seriously, thank you big time!! My coding is not that great and I searched the whole internet for something similar but nothing. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. edit_post is checking after each post update. (you can also use save_post). wp_insert_post works only then a post is a created.